# Android apk includes only armeabi-v7a and x86 native libraries

Tags: android, jenkins, android-ndk, apk

My release apk that taken from android studio includes "**armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips"** folders in /lib folder but if i take the apk from jenkins it includes only **"armeabi-v7a"** and **"x86"** folders.

But this is my not real problem. The problem is that none of that lib folders does not include some `.so` files. Here is error log:

```
Failed to load native library: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/==/lib/arm, /data/app/==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libcardioDecider.so"
```

When I take the apk from android studio by generate signed apk, size of the apk is 
82.7 MB. But if I take the apk from jenkins size of the apk is 66 MB.

Here is comparison of two apks:
[image]

And I have

```
ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips"
}
```

in my app.gradle.

Comment: Note that the `armeabi` and `mips` ABIs no longer are supported for Android. It's possible that your jenkins build server has a newer Gradle plugin installed that won't package libraries for those ABIs into the APK. The latest NDK releases also don't support `armeabi` or `mips` - but in that case there should be build errors.

Comment: On the face of it, your Jenkins build does not actually build the C++ code. It does package some native libraries, but most likely these came prebuilt with 3rd party dependencies.